# Difference between Normal Image Insert and insert as Bulk BLOB

Tags: sql, image, blob

I have `sql` database with table Images, in that table there are 2 `Columns` `ID` (identity), DisplayImage (image). Table has 2 rows for first row i have written

```
insert into Image values(1,'Libraries\Pictures\Lotus.jpg')
```

and 2nd row as

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Image] ([Id],Images)
SELECT 2,
(select * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB)
```

Here is the code for reading the image

```
WebClient instanceHTTP = new WebClient();
            Uri MyUri = new Uri("http://localhost:52293/WebSite/ImageHandler.ashx?ImageId=" + TextBox5.Text);    //TextBox5.Text for id i.e 1 or 2
            Stream returnValue;
        returnValue = instanceHTTP.OpenRead(MyUri);


 **System.Drawing.Image MyImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(returnValue);**  
// Error if id=1 used i.e normal insert

        bytearray = imageToByteArray(MyImage);

                    MyImage.Dispose();
```

if i use id 1 that is normal insert than it gives error that invalid Parmeter
but if i use id 2 it runs properly.
So what is the difference?? and what changes i have to make in order to runn normal insert image.. I dont want to use AS `BLOB` in insert statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the insert 1 statement insert string 'Libraries\Pictures\Lotus.jpg' instead of image.
thats why when you were accessing it gives invalid parameter error.

if you have to store image you have to use BLOB